# anbox is preventing me from installing anything

Tags: dpkg, anbox

I am running Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS. I tried to install anbox, a progam to run an Android emulator on my computer.  It didn't work.  I am ok with that, I just won't use it.  But now I can't install anything, because whenever I try, it says:

```
ERROR: Cannot create report: [Errno 17] File exists: '/var/crash/anbox-modules-dkms.0.crash'
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 5.4.0-47-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/anbox/1/build/make.log for more information.
dpkg: error processing package anbox-modules-dkms (--configure):
 installed anbox-modules-dkms package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 10
Errors were encountered while processing:
 anbox-modules-dkms
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I have tried removing and purging anbox but to no avail. And it doesn't matter what I am trying to install it comes up with the same error that includes the Anbox reference.  I don't have the backup capabilities right now to cover what I have on this SSD or else I would just back it up, wipe the drive and reinstall Ubuntu.  What should I do to fix this?

Comment: What are the steps you followed to install anbox? Did you refer any tutorial for installing it? If yes, please [edit] your question and add the tutorial link.

Answer (score 1):

I tried this command and it worked for me:

```
sudo apt purge anbox-modules-dkms
```